# redux mapdispatchtoprops state values of other components

Tags: redux, react-redux

This question may be silly, but for some reason I cannot find what I want to. I have a component which has two inputs, if any one of the input changes, I have to dispatch an action to saga to find some info from backend, so I have send both these values. When values are changed in one of the components I dispatch with new value and set it in redux store, for sending request to backend I need the other input value which is already set in redux store, how should I do this?

Below is the component and usecase, I want both duration and date values in change functions.

```
export class Options extends React.Component { // eslint-disable-line react/prefer-stateless-function
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <SelectField
          name={"duration"}
          value={this.props.duration}
          onChange={this.props.durationChanged}
        >
          <MenuItem key={1}  value={1} primaryText={"option1"} />
          <MenuItem key={2}  value={2} primaryText={"option2"} />
          <MenuItem key={3}  value={3} primaryText={"option3"} />
          <MenuItem key={4} value={4} primaryText={"option4"} />
        </SelectField>
        <DatePicker
          value={this.props.date}
          onChange={this.props.dateChanged}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = createStructuredSelector({
  date: makeSelectDate(),
  duration: makeSelectDuration(),
});

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch, a, b) {
  return {
    dispatch,
    dateChanged: (any, date) => {
      dispatch(changeDate(date));
      //I want other duration value to dispatch an action to backend
    },
    durationChanged: (event, index, value) => {
      dispatch(changeDuration(value));
      //I want other date value to dispatch an action to backend
    }
  };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Options);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, you need do:

1) Set only one prop "onChange" as function. And add props to define values on init. It like initValueDuration.

2) Set state with 3 fields

3) Add method onChange(state). This method will call:  this.prop.onChange(this.state)

Answer (score 0):

Say you have the two states `duration, date` in `yourReducer`. Then, you need two functions: `durationChanged, dateChanged`.

```
function durationChanged(newDuration) {
    return (dispatch: Redux.Dispatch<any>, getState: () => RootState) => {
        dispatch({
            type: "DURATION_CHANGED",
            payload: newDuration
        });
        const date = getState().yourReducer.date;
        yourAsyncCallToTheBackEnd(newDuration, date);
        ...
    }
}

function dateChanged(newDate) {
    return (dispatch: Redux.Dispatch<any>, getState: () => RootState) => {
        dispatch({
            type: "DATE_CHANGED",
            payload: newDate
        });
        const duration = getState().yourReducer.duration;
        yourAsyncCallToTheBackEnd(duration, newDate);
        ...
   }
}
```

In your `mapDispatchToProps`, you add

```
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch: Redux.Dispatch<any>, ownProps: any): any{
    return {
        durationChanged: (newValue) => durationChanged(newValue),
        dateChanged: (newValue) => dateChanged(newValue)
    };
}
```

In yourReducer, you check the type of the action and change the corresponding state.
In your onChange handler of date input, you do `this.props.dateChanged(event.target.value)`

Checkout the [redux-thunk](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk)

Comment: To make it simple, you can combine the two functions into one, just pass the action types as an argument.